# Apache2 | Virtual Host shows 404

Tags: server, apache2, virtualhost

I'm trying to create new virtual host. So I created a new file `mrpdf` in `apache2/sites-available`

mrpdf file below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName supportcenter.sevplcorp.com/mrpdf/Root
  DocumentRoot /media/MR_Docs/Root/
  <Directory /media/MR_Docs/Root/>
   Options -SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride None
   Order allow,deny
   allow from all
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I inserted a new line in `etc/hosts`

```
127.0.1.1   supportcenter.sevplcorp.com/mrpdf/Root
```

then I run following commands

```
sudo a2ensite mrpdf
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Now I check my browser `https://supportcenter.sevplcorp.com/mrpdf/Root`

It shows **`404 Not Found`**

Any solution?

Comment: This new line in `/etc/hosts` must be: `127.0.0.1   supportcenter.sevplcorp.com`. Also `mrpdf` must become `mrpdf.conf`. You don't have SSL configuration, so you need use `http://`. The directive server name must be `ServerName supportcenter.sevplcorp.com`. You can reach the content of `/media/MR_Docs/Root` through the address: `http://supportcenter.sevplcorp.com`, because it is set as `DocumentRoot`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use only host name in `hosts` file, so use this content of `/etc/hosts/`

```
127.0.1.1   supportcenter.sevplcorp.com
```

Also the `ServerName` should contain only host name and not the path after `/`

After that, your page will be available at http://supportcenter.sevplcorp.com

Comment: I have update the answer. Please also try log files possibly in `/var/log/apache2/...` to see more

Comment: where I have to give permission for that file media/MR_Docs/Root